# Two position in on OnBindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I want to take two pictures in one column in my app. I'm used RecyclerView and must work with *position* but when I try to download pictures from API I have in first column pictures 1 then pictures 2 but in another column I have piture 2 and picture 3. In different column I have the same last and first element, how can I change this behavior?

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PhotoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Uri image_uri_one = Uri.parse(call.get(position).getImage_url());
        Context context = holder.photo_one.getContext();
        Picasso.with(context).load(image_uri_one).into(holder.photo_one);
        Uri image_uri_two = Uri.parse(call.get(position+1).getImage_url());
        Context context1 = holder.photo_two.getContext();
        Picasso.with(context1).load(image_uri_two).into(holder.photo_two);
    }
```

Comment: which LayoutManager are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first recyclerview row you getting posision 0 and you getting first picture with posision 0 and second picture with posision 1. For the second row you getting 1 and 2. So you should multiplay `int posision` by 2 before you use it.

Something like this:

`@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PhotoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int newPosition = posision*2;
        Uri image_uri_one = Uri.parse(call.get(newPosition).getImage_url());
        Context context = holder.photo_one.getContext();
        Picasso.with(context).load(image_uri_one).into(holder.photo_one);
        Uri image_uri_two = Uri.parse(call.get(newPosition+1).getImage_url());
        Context context1 = holder.photo_two.getContext();
        Picasso.with(context1).load(image_uri_two).into(holder.photo_two);
    }`